# Why is service unavailable for net.tcp?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a service that works fine when I access it in via HTTP.  When I try to access it via net.tcp, I get this message:

> The message could not be dispatched because the service at the
>   endpoint address [net.tcp address here] is unavailable for the
>   protocol of the address.

I'm using IIS6.  I do have net.tcp bound to a port number for the website.  The service has net.tcp defined in advanced bindings.  I did a

> netstat -ona:find "50099"

and two listening TCP entries showed up.  Other services work fine over net.tcp on port 50099.

The web.config looks like this:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp//localhost:50099/MyServiceName/MyServiceName.svc" 
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="netTcpEndpoint"
          contract="MyServiceNameContract" 
          name="netTcpEndpoint">
  <identity>
    <servicePrincipalName value="localhost"/>
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working for net.tcp?

Comment: are you hosting the service under IIS? Does it work with the default `net.tcp` port 808?

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I am using IIS6.  Other services work fine on port 50099.

Comment: Do you have port sharing enabled for in the binding for this particular service?

Comment: I would try to make it work on the default 808 port first, then attempt to change to some other port number. That's how i run my duplex `net.tcp` service.

Comment: 808 produces this error: Could not connect to [service address].  The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.042.  TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808.

Comment: Remember there's a couple places in IIS you have to set port 808 in order for it to work properly. I can post a couple of print screens in case you think it could be helpful to you. Also, your config file has to account for that. If you post the complete `<system.serviceModel>` section of your config file i can check it.

Comment: @jstreet: I think this is just creating a new problem.  50099 already works so chasing another port is a waste of time.

Comment: OK, no problem, it's up to you. Just realize that if you cannot make it work on the default port... well, the degree of difficulty trying to make it on a different port is higher. But like i said, it's up to you. And if you post the `<system.serviceModel>` section of your config file i can still check it for you.

Comment: Yeah - thanks anyway.